# Bookdown rendering only blank pages

Tags: r, bookdown

I am new to Bookdown. I am setting up a test book. When I go to render the book, the first page (index.Rmd) renders correctly and builds the correct TOC on the left. However, clicking any link in the TOC shows me only a blank page. In the _book folder, all internal pages are 0-byte HTML files.

I found several others [had this problem on the RStudio forums](https://community.rstudio.com/t/bookdown-blank-output-files-basically-the-output-in-html-is-blank-an-no-rmd-data-is-shown/8446.) but no solution was posted.

Just in case, here is my index.html YAML:

```
--- 
title: "Test Title"
author: "My Name"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
site: bookdown::bookdown_site
output: bookdown::gitbook
documentclass: book
bibliography: [book.bib]
biblio-style: apalike
link-citations: yes
github-repo: acircleda/RESMHandbook
description: "descirption"
---
```

Note: I cloned the [bookdown minimal example](https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown-demo) and had the same issue

Comment: Do you get any errors? What is the output from knitr?

Comment: don´t use the knit button in RStudio, use `bookdown::render("index.Rmd")`

Comment: @J_F, using `bookdown::render_book("index.Rmd")` worked! I was surprised that the book did not automatically open. Why doesn't the knit to gitbook button work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use `bookdown::render_book("index.Rmd")` instead of using the knit button.